# How to get data from an R script securely emailed to me from unknown users?

Tags: r, matlab, email, dropbox, google-drive-api

There are various forums on here giving examples of how to email data from an R script to someone. However, In my project I am having users run an R script, and then have that R script somehow communicate the results generated by the user to me. The first part of the script is already written in R, so a solution in R is much preferred. (besides matlab and R I have very limited knowledge of other languages, I unfortunately don't know PHP)

The problem is that the identity of the user must be protected such that no one can identify the person who ran the script from the file they send to me or deposit somewhere, so I can't just use their email address in the from line. What are my options here? Could I set up an email account for them to email it to me? Could I have it so that the results are automatically uploaded to a repository online (maybe dropbox or google drive)? How can I do these things securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send mail using the [SendMailR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/sendmailR.pdf). There is no requirement that the from address be a real e-mail address. Use your own SMTP server as the server settings.

Comment: That sounds great, I get an error, that I think is fixed by configuring my mailing system. My question is, how can I expect these many other users to go through a complicated configuration process so they don't get this error. Is there anyway for this to be checked by the R script so they don't have to do this by hand? 

Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
  localhost:25 cannot be opened

Comment: You can include the settings in the script using either the `control` option on the `sendmail` call or the `sendmail_options` function. They can use your settings, they don't need their own.

Comment: I figured out the problem it had to do with SendMailR not being compatible with authentication. The get around is to use gmail's smtp that doesn't require authentication instead of gmail's standard smtp .